# Is there a way to implement inner classes in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, inner-classes

```
//access to a Constant if it was like another language 
ImageWeather.Desktop.cloud; 
 
//What i wanted ( not working because there is no inner class)
class ImageWeather {
      class Desktop {
         static const String cloud = 'assets/images/DesktopCloud.png';
         static const String noCloud = 'assets/images/DesktopNoCloud.png';
         static const String rain = 'assets/images/DesktopRain.png';
   }  
      class Phone{
         static const String cloud = 'assets/images/PhoneCloud.png';
         static const String noCloud = 'assets/images/PhoneNoCloud.png';
         static const String rain = 'assets/images/PhoneRain.png';
   }
}

//access to a String like an inner class with new code
ImageWeather.desktop.cloud;


class ImageWeather {
   static final Desktop desktop = Desktop();
   static final Phone phone = Phone();
}

class Desktop {
   get cloud => 'assets/images/DesktopCloud.png';
   get noCloud => 'assets/images/DesktopNoCloud.png';
   get rain => 'assets/images/DesktopRain.png';
}
class Phone {
   get cloud => 'assets/images/PhoneCloud.png';
   get noCloud => 'assets/images/PhoneNoCloud.png';
   get rain => 'assets/images/PhoneRain.png';
```

}

I'm currently learning Dart and I just see that I can't use an inner class.
Is there a way to write something similar to inner classes in Dart?

Comment: The inner-class pattern is unusual. The class design of the otter class doesn't follow a "single responsibility" principle. In this case a single class (`ImageWeather`) is defining two different classes. So it's not apparenlt in the API what you are actually accessing. So using two different classes provide a clear uncoupled relationship between the two classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not using Inner Classes is a good or bad thing is subjective. Different developers will have different opinions.

However, if you wish to make `Desktop` and `Phone` only visible to `ImageWeather`, you can write the three classes within a single package and rename the 'inner' classes `_Desktop` and `_Phone`, thus making them only visible within that package.